# Django M2M queryset with multiple instances and Q

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-q

I have the following models:

```
class Thematics(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Pathology(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Organ(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Surgerytype(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Content(models.Model):
    thematics = models.ManyToManyField(Thematics, null=True, blank=True)
    pathology = models.ManyToManyField(Pathology, null=True, blank=True)
    organs = models.ManyToManyField(Organ, null=True, blank=True)
    surgery = models.ManyToManyField(Surgerytype, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a lot of Content instances, which themselves have a lot of M2M instances related to them. You can think of Surgerytypes as tags.

I have this query:

```
content = Content.objects.all()
# surgeries is an array of Surgerytype instances titles

query = content.filter(Q(surgery__title__in=surgeries)
```

For simplicity I will focus on one M2M model, Surgerytype, and admit that I could replicate then chain the query with the 3 other models.

I create 3 instances of Surgerytype with title: "Diagnosis", "Surgery", "Therapeutic"
I then create 3 instances of Content to which I add these M2M relations with  surgery (the M2M to Surgerytype)

- Content instance 1 --> add(Diagnosis)
- Content instance 2 --> add(Diagnosis, Surgery)
- Content instance 3 --> add (Diagnosis, Surgery, Therapeutic)

The whole idea here is to have a dynamic filtering by the client/doctor who can choose tags to get to the type of content he needs.

So if he/she clicks :

- on Diagnosis and no other tag, the doctor should see Content instance 1,2 and 3.
- on Diagnosis and Surgery or just Surgery, the doctor should see Content instance 2 and 3
- on Diagnosis, Surgery, Therapeutic or just Therapeutic, the doctor should see Content instance 3
- On Diagnosis and Therapeutic, the doctor should see Content 3

So this is an AND problematic.

When I ajax send to my backend a tag (i.e. a Surgerytype instance title), all good the query returns all the instances of Content that include this tag. Now, the problem is that if I select two tags, the queryset returns nothing instead of all Content instances that include these 2 tags and possibly more tags. I have found on SO how to do this for 1 M2M model in the Content model but it is quite dirty and not scalable at all (there are 3 other M2M/filters to add in the real Content model). 
 Any ideas? Found many questions related to the subject but it doesn't seem to have a definitive, scalable answer. Many thanks to you all

Comment: Can you share some sample data? If you just use one tag at a time on those two tags that don't work, do you get results?

Comment: Thanks Brian, I just updated the whole thing to make it clearer. Is it ok?